# Misaligned column headings using sScrollX / sScrollY

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am trying to put `2px solid #fff` border on all td and th on my table. problem I have is once table is converted to jquery datatable the header cell borders do not align with the body cell borders.

I have tried placing in css

```
table td, table th {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

also tried `table-border` class and `cell-border` class

[image]

I tehn tried putting class names on all headers then adjusting the width for the ones that do not align, problem with this is, once i got to the 15th column to align it does not

I put following code in `initComplete`

```
$(".header_SITE, .header_JVCO_ID").css("padding-right","32px"); // 1st 2 columns
            $(".header_INCIDENT_NUMBER, .header_CRQ ").css("padding-right","31px"); //15 and 16th column
```

This problem seems to occur when I add the following options in datatables

```
'sScrollX': '100%',
        'scrollX': true,
        'sScrollY': ($(window).height()-520),
        scrollCollapse: true,
'bScrollCollapse': true,
```

I have now also tried `oTable.columns.adjust().draw();` which had no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corrected problem by updating and using all the source files specified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/UvjnT/1166/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--datatabler-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--buttons-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


<!--FixedColumns-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<!--FixedHeader-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

<!--FixedHeader-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>


<!--FixedHeader-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```